# Meu cron laravel não está sendo executado

Tags: laravel, cron

Estou tentando fazer um cron no laravel pra enviar um email a cada 1 minuto, porém nenhum e-mail foi enviado até agora.

Meu **EmailAdocaoCron.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\animalAdocao;
use Mail;


class EmailAdocaoCron extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'example:cron';
    protected $description = 'Command E-mail';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $animaisAdocao = animalAdocao::all();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($animaisAdocao); $i++){

            $data = array(
                'apelido' => $animaisAdocao[$i]['apelido']
            );

            Mail::send('emailadocaoconfirmacao', $data, function ($message) use ($animaisAdocao, $i){
                $message->from('renatoveronese600@gmail.com', 'Ei, email teste')->subject('Confirmação do seu anúncio');
                $message->to($animaisAdocao[$i]['email_contato']);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Meu kernel.php:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\EmailAdocaoCron::class
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('example:cron')->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Está faltando alguma coisa?

**Essa é minha tabela na qual eu pego os email para enviar:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: configurou o serviço de envio SMTP?

Comment: Sim, eu consegui, tem que criar um arquivo .bat e usar com o xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimente correr no terminal do seu projecto: php artisan example:cron e veja se existe algum erro. Se existir um erro, é corrigir o que estiver mal.

Paralelamente, para as crons funcionarem, é necessário adicionar uma cron, ao próprio servidor onde está alojada a aplicação, ou seja, no terminal escrever:

```
crontab -e
```

e adicionar a seguinte linha (Alterando os nomes para os correctos)

```
 * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Mais informação aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction

Comment: Fiz algo parecido, usei o xampp para rodar o cron